# Is there a clean way to implement ancestor style triggers in XAML WPF

Tags: css, wpf, stylesheet

I'm creating some styles for a basic property grid. The XAML for an example would be

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource propertyGrid}" Orientation="Vertical"  >

    <ItemsControl Tag="property">
        <Label>Nodes</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Nodes}"/>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Tag="property">
        <Label >Major Diameter</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MajorDiameter}"/>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Tag="property">
        <Label>Minor Diameter</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MinorDiameter}"/>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Tag="property">
        <Label>Excenter</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Excenter}"> </TextBox>
    </ItemsControl>

</StackPanel>
```

and my styling follows this logic. Labels or TextBoxes within
an ItemsControl with Tag `property` get special styling. If I
was doing this as psuedo CSS I'd write

```
ItemsControl.property Label {
    Grid.Row: 0;
    FontWeight: bold;
    Padding:0,4,0,0;
}

ItemsControl.property TextBox {
    Grid.Row: 1;
    FontWeight: bold;
}
```

after much teeth gnashing I figured out one way to do this and this
was to use DataTriggers to look back up the tree rather than the
CSS mentality to look down the tree. However I'm rather horrified
by the verbosity of it. See below.

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="propertyGrid">
    <Style.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=Tag}" Value="property">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=Tag}" Value="property">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="property">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="property">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="Auto">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

My question is. Is there a shortcut or better notation for doing this? I'm very
tempted to write a WPFCSS compiler to deal with this ;) Could I
write a MarkupExtension to clean it up. I would prefer any solutions to work
at design time as well if possible.

For example would it be possible to write an extension such as

```
<AncestorTrigger TargetType="ItemsControl" Path="Tag" Value="property">
    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
</AncestorTrigger>
```

?  This would be much easier than remembering how to write

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=Tag}" Value="property">
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom behavior to solve this that also works at design time. The markup will

```
<DataTrigger 
    WPF:WhenParentTag.TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" Value="property">

    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,0"/>

</DataTrigger>
```

which is a bit more sane. The code for the extension is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace My.WPF
{
    public static class WhenParentTag
    {

        static WhenParentTag()
        {}

        public static readonly DependencyProperty 
            TargetTypeProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
            ( "TargetType"
            , typeof(Type)
            , typeof(WhenParentTag)
            , new PropertyMetadata(null, TargetTypeChanged));

        public static void 
            TargetTypeChanged
            ( DependencyObject  dob
            , DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var trigger = dob as DataTrigger;
            if(trigger==null){
                return;
            }

            var type = e.NewValue as Type;
            if (type == null)
                return;

            var binding = new Binding();
            var rel = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = type };
            binding.RelativeSource = rel;
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Tag");
            trigger.Binding = binding;
        }

        public static Type
            GetTargetType
            ( DataTrigger dp)
        {
            return (Type)dp.GetValue(TargetTypeProperty);
        }

        public static void
            SetTargetType
            ( DataTrigger dp,
            Type value)
        {
            dp.SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Improvement suggestions are welcome.